# Reduced and not reduced points of a scheme.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Here is a small paragraph of a course of "Anwar Alameddin" that i found on the net accidently, and that i try to understand clearly, about intersection theory :

> Let $ k $ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic different
>   than $2$ and $ 3 $, such that $ f = y^2 - x^3 + 2x - 2 $ and $ g_c = y-c $ be two irreducible polynomials in $ k[x,y] $, for $ x \in k $.
>
> Then, $ f $ and $ g_c $ give rise to two closed subschemes $ F $ and $ G_c $ of $ \mathbb{A}_{k}^2 $, induced by the surjections of ring
>   homomorphisms : $ \varphi_f : k[x,y] \to k[x,y] / (f) $ and $ \varphi_{g_{c}} : k[x,y] \to k[x,y] / ( g_c ) $, respectively.
>
> Let $ F.G_c $ denote the scheme-theoretic intersection of $ F $ and $ G_c $, i.e : the pull-back of the closed subschemes diagram in $ \mathrm{Sch} / k $ : $$ \xymatrix{
>      F.G_c \ar[r] \ar[d] & G_c \ar[d] \\
>      F \ar[r] & \mathbb{A}_{k}^1   } $$ Hence, $ F.G_c = \mathrm{Spec} k[x,y] / (f,g_c ) $. In contrast to set-theoretic intersection, the
>   irreducible components of scheme-theoretic intersection of two reduced
>   schemes are not necessary reduced.
>
> For example, for $ c = \pm \sqrt{ 2 - \dfrac{4}{3} \sqrt{ \dfrac{2}{3} } } $, then straightforward calculations show that :
>
> $$ F.G_c = \mathrm{Spec} k[x,y] / \Big( y^2  - x^3 + 2 x - 2 , y - \sqrt{ 2 - \dfrac{4}{3} \sqrt{ \dfrac{2}{3} } } \Big) $$  $$ \simeq \mathrm{Spec}
> > k[x,y] / \Big( (x - \sqrt{ \dfrac{2}{3} } )^2 ( x + 2 \sqrt{ \dfrac{2}{3} } ) \Big) $$
>
> $$ \simeq \mathrm{Spec} k[x] / \Big( x - \sqrt{ \dfrac{2}{3} } \Big)^2 \coprod \mathrm{Spec} k[x] / \Big( x + 2 \sqrt{ \dfrac{2}{3} } \Big) $$ 
>   Hence, the
>   intesection $ F.G_c $ consists of two rational points, with underlying
>   topological points $ |P| = \Big( \sqrt{ \dfrac{2}{3} } , c \Big) $ and $ |Q| = \Big( -2 \sqrt{ \dfrac{2}{3} } , c \Big) $. These points are intrinsically
>   different from each other, that $Q$ is reduced, whereas $ P $ is not.

My question is :

Why does $ |P| $ reduced, but $ |Q| $ is not reduced ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you asking why  $ \mathrm{Spec} k[x] / \Big( x - \sqrt{ \dfrac{2}{3} } \Big)^2$ is not reduced but $\mathrm{Spec} k[x] / \Big( x + 2 \sqrt{ \dfrac{2}{3} } \Big) $ is?

Comment: Yes, sorry for this long paragraph that i wrote.  :-)

Comment: For the first one, a ring of the form $A/I^2$ with $I\neq I^2$ is never reduced. The second one is isomorphic to $k$

Comment: $ \forall x \in I \backslash I^2 $ : $ \overline{x} \in A / I^2 $ and $ \overline{x} \neq \overline{0} $.
Consequently : $ \overline{x}^2 = \overline{ x^{2} } = \overline{0} $ because : $ x^2 \in I^2 $.
Consequently : $ \overline{x} $ is nilpotent, so that : $ A / I^2 $ is not reduced.  :-)

Comment: But, i still not understand why does $ \mathrm{Spec} k[x]/ \Big( x - \sqrt{ \dfrac{ 2}{3} } \Big)^2 $ not reduced. Any help please ? Thank you in advance.  :-D